# How to remove Padding from DrawerHeader

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Here's my `DrawerHeader` :

```
class MyDrawerHeader extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyDrawerHeaderState createState() => _MyDrawerHeaderState();
}

class _MyDrawerHeaderState extends State<MyDrawerHeader> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DrawerHeader(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      child: Center(child: Text('Header', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline))
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see I made the `Padding` and `Margin` from the `DrawerHeader` be `0`, but this is how my Header is being shown:

[image: Big Drawer Header]

It's just too big and I can't make it smaller. I have no idea why its being rendered this way, I looked into `DrawerHeader` source code and I can't see anything in there overriding my `Padding` or `Margin`.

Just to be sure the problem is in `DrawerHeader`, this is what Happens when I substitute it for a `Container`:

[image: Small Header]

It works as it should!

Am I missing something, or is this a bug in Flutter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is always padding on `DrawerHeader`. If you look in sources:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  assert(debugCheckHasMaterial(context));
  assert(debugCheckHasMediaQuery(context));
  final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
  final double statusBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
  return Container(
    height: statusBarHeight + _kDrawerHeaderHeight,
    margin: margin,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border(
        bottom: Divider.createBorderSide(context),
      ),
    ),
    child: AnimatedContainer(
      padding: padding.add(EdgeInsets.only(top: statusBarHeight)),
      decoration: decoration,
      duration: duration,
      curve: curve,
      child: child == null ? null : DefaultTextStyle(
        style: theme.textTheme.body2,
        child: MediaQuery.removePadding(
          context: context,
          removeTop: true,
          child: child,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

You can customize this code:

`height: statusBarHeight + _kDrawerHeaderHeight` - here is total height of header

`padding: padding.add(EdgeInsets.only(top: statusBarHeight))` - here is padding of child element in `DrawerHeader`

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right! `_kDrawerHeaderHeight` is defined on the top of the class, I missed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: [
              DrawerHeader(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                child: Container(
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("Home"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for your answer. Rather than just posting a block of code, can you give a short explanation to what the issue is you solved and how you solved it? This will help people who find this question in the future to better understand the issue and how to deal with it.

Comment: padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0), Works for me. Thanks

Comment: Previous comment from @NaeemIbrahim should be the accepted answer. Simplest solution that works and directly addresses op's request.

Comment: Instead of `padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0)` you could just do `padding: EdgeInsets.zero`.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your drawer by the code below

```
drawer: Drawer(
    child: DrawerHeader(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Text('Header', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```